# ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer. in colab.google

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to work on email spam detection using python code, but I am getting an error. I am trying to get spam mails as 1 and non spam mails as 0. I have given my code and error below.i

code  :-

```
dt['Spam'] = dt['type'].map( {'Spam' : 1 , 'ham' : 0} ).astype(int)
```

my error  :-

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-fa830e0e48eb> in <module>()
----> 1 dt['Spam'] = dt['type'].map( {'Spam' : 1 , 'ham' : 0} ).astype(int)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    966 
    967         if not np.isfinite(arr).all():
--> 968             raise ValueError("Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer")
    969 
    970     elif is_object_dtype(arr):

ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dt = dt.dropna()
dt['Spam'] = dt['type'].map({'Spam' : 1, 'ham' : 0}).astype('int64')
```

or this:

```
dt['type'] = dt['type'].replace(np.inf, np.nan)
dt = dt.dropna()
dt['Spam'] = dt['type'].map({'Spam' : 1, 'ham' : 0}).astype('int64')
```